# HTC One X Does not charge or turn on

Tags: charging, boot, htc-one-x

A day ago my HTC One X would not turn on. When I booted into developer mode it said at the top "*****LOCKED*****" and "Security Warning" (or something similar). It also said "cpu-bootmode: disabled". I was able to get it to boot with recovery mode but it would just freeze after a minute and I would have to restart the phone through the above process.

Now, the battery is dead because it froze with its screen on (draining all the battery). It won't boot into developer mode or safe mode. It also doesn't charge (atleast I think so because I don't see the LED indicator light up).

Any ideas on how to charge my phone, fix the issue or even what the issue is?

I did not root my phone but I did install Apex Launcher (about a month ago).

Thanks,

Comment: What is *developer mode*? Never heard of it... care to post a screenshot or camera shot of it?

Comment: I was talking about this. The boot menu. I think someone told me it was a developer mode and I just used that term. http://www.hardreset.eu/images/google_nexus_one_hard_reset.jpg

Comment: That's referring to the Google Nexus One.....

Comment: I just found a picture online of what I was talking about. I dont have my HTC One X anymore to take a screenshot

Answer (score 1):

This is awfully strange if you did not root your device - because normally, these are symptoms of a bricked device.

If you can get into recovery, please could you erase your data? You can attempt to get into recovery by holding the recovery key combo (minus the power button), and then plugging the charger in.

If this doesn't work - after erasing your data, then I would suggest taking it to a repair shop - you never rooted it, so your warranty is therefore still intact.

Comment: I can't seem to get into the developer menu anymore (I think it is because the battery has been drained). Do you think the phone will charge even if there is no indication by the LED if it is plugged in?